# Which other frameworks like OAuth are available?

Tags: security, oauth, cloud, oauth-2.0, owncloud

I wish to connect ownCloud to a server in a secure way. However OAuth is not compatible with ownCloud.

Answer (score 0):

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/30/openid-oauth-saml/ describes the characteristics of three standards: openid, oauth2 and SAML.

There are also other web authorization protocols around, e.g. https://github.com/hueniverse/oz. However I doubt that any of these are supported in ownCloud.

According to https://owncloud.org/news/introducing-oauth2-secure-authorization-flow/, ownCould now supports OAuth. I would recomment to stick with OAuth.

You may also like to try https://nextcloud.com/. It does support OAuth. Documentation is scarce, however.